# How to implement Short URL in asp.net 2.0 version

Tags: asp.net, short-url

is it possible to implement short urls in asp.net 2.0 version. please give me the idea in such a by which i can make any big url short and also again to get back the long url back from short url. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a table that connect the short url to the natural one.

so you have  `www.tny.com/mshe.aspx` that point to `www.tny.com/MyNormalBigOneUrl.aspx`

and on the `global.asax`, on `Application_BeginRequest`, when you see a small url you make the translation to the normal one, via your table, and if you find a mutch you just call the `Redirect("MyNormalBigOneUrl.aspx")`

If you like to keep the small urls you can make the translator via the `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath`

Alternative you can have to diferent sites, one with small name `www.tny.com`, and one normal site, `www.mynormalsite.com`, and you make the redirect only on the tiny site.